# How can I use .map on an array to create a new JSON object for each item?

Tags: arrays, json

how can I use `map` on an array to map each item to a new JSON structure? 
For example my original array looks like this:

```
result= [
 {
  "pageIndex":1,
  "pageName":"home",
  "cssConfiguration":"fa fa-home"
 }, ...]
```

And I want to use .map to create a different structure for the JSON objects, for example:

```
modifiedResult = [
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"Home"
},...]
```

I've tried to do something like this:

```
result.map((resultItem) => { name: resultItem["pageName"], id:resultItem["pageIndex"]});
```

But it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your approach are missing the parentheses within the handler:

```
result.map((resultItem) => { name: resultItem["pageName"], id:resultItem["pageIndex"]});
                           ^
```

You can use the function `map` and `destructuring-assignment` as follow:

```js
let arr = [ {  "pageIndex":1,  "pageName":"home",  "cssConfiguration":"fa fa-home" }],
    result = arr.map(({pageIndex: id, pageName: name}) => ({id, name}));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The parentheses were the problem.

Comment: @SebastianI. yw `(:`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`:

```
const result = arr.map(({pageIndex, pageName}) => ({id: pageIndex, name: pageName}))
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
 {
  "pageIndex":1,
  "pageName":"home",
  "cssConfiguration":"fa fa-home"
 }]
 
 const result = arr.map(({pageIndex, pageName}) => ({id: pageIndex, name: pageName}))
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: Oh.. all I had to do was to add some brackets .. `()`. Thank you.